# Generating cert_override file manually for Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-profile, scientific-linux

I am currently using a self-signed certificate that I don't have the option of re-generating, and every time I install our software on a target machine, the first time Firefox is opened to our homepage, there is an "untrusted" page where we have to create an exception for the page. I would like to avoid this, and the cert_override.txt file that is part of the user profile unfortunately can't just be drag-and-dropped onto a new system because the fingerprint is different.

Is there a way to generate this file myself? Or can someone explain to me how the fingerprint (the piece of information in the file that looks like a really long MAC address) is generated so I can create the cert_override.txt file when the software is first installed?

So far I have had no luck finding any information on generating this file.

If it matters, we are using Firefox 60 on Scientific Linux 6.4 (2.6.32-754).

Answer (score 0):

Some one has Pythonized an API for that `cert_override.txt`.

Hope that helps.

https://github.com/Osmose/firefox-cert-override